# Load XML document in Windows CE using C #

Tags: c#, xml, compact-framework, windows-ce

I´m trying to load a XML document in Windows CE using C#, however i keep getting some strange errors in debugging. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace cpap3
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Display()
    {

        XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();

        docXML.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)+"\\modulos.xml");


        XmlElement nodRoot = docXML.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList nodItems = nodRoot.GetElementsByTagName("Modulos");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodItems.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(nodItems[i].InnerXml);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodItems.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(nodItems[i].InnerXml);

    }

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        Display();           

        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The XML file is in the right place, and I've tried several locations for the file. This is the error I'm getting.

{"An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly containing it cannot be found An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly containing it cannot be found"}

The error occurs when I load the XML file:

docXML.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)+"\modulos.xml");

Here is the exception detail:

```
System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled
  Message="An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly   containing it cannot be found An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly containing it cannot be found"
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=31
  SourceUri="file:///Windows/Programs/modulos.xml"
  StackTrace:
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.CheckEncoding()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load()
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load()
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load()
at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Display()
at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main()
```

---------------EDIT--------------

It took me a while but now I have real error reports :)... Here is the actual error.

```
"System does not support 'iso-8859-1' encoding. Line 1, position 31."
```

I've tried saving my file with different encodings but i keep on getting the same error. Any solutions?

---------------EDIT-----------------
I've solved it :D . I was changing the encoding using notepad, but i forgot I had written an encoding tag in the XML file, and that was causing this problem. Stupid mistake. :(

Comment: What line yields the error? Also, can you inspect the InnerException contained inside the exception you get? More information may be contained there.

Comment: The error is here:  docXML.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)+"\\modulos.xml");

Comment: Do you get the same error when using the emulator? Alternatively, you could consider deploying the resource assemblies with the error messages in, to get the real error message.

Comment: I get a can't find file error in the emulator. I didn't understand what you're saying with deploying resource assemblies with the error messages... :s

Comment: maybe you should try re-saving your xml file as unicode, you can use notepad on your development workstation for this.

Comment: Yes, the XML is valid, I've managed to read it using classic ASP and jquery. I've tried to save it as unicode but it didn't change anything...

Comment: Did you make sure Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) is returning the value you expect?

Comment: Yes. I've printed the value from Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs). I've also tried to place the file in the root of the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually you have to talk with the one that built your WinCE OS image to include also the ".Net Compact Framework 3.5 Localized String Resources" by default you will have en-US, but you can select also something else, for example: Portuguese. The option is in Catalog Items View -> Core OS -> Windows Embedded Compact -> Applications and Services Development -> .NET Compact Framework 3.5 -> .Net Compact Framework 3.5 -> .Net Compact Framework 3.5 Localized String Resources

See attached picture:
[image: Catalog Item View]

You will have to remake the OS image and also the SDK if you are using one. After this you should no longer have this error.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look in platform builder and i was suspecting that this could be the problem. I am right now building a new image. I hope it solves my problem. I will update as soon as the new image is ready.

Comment: This is only going to add the string resources (which can be done by manually running the CAB file on the device).  It's not going to eliminate the error, it's just going to give hime error text for the error he has.

Comment: Obviously he has a different error there, either the XML is not well-formed or there is a programming mistake. But from I've understood he is debugging the code and it's getting this error. The localized resources will help him to debug the code.

Comment: @ctake Yes, also including in the installer the CAB file for the localized resources would help, but is not natural. For example when I am developing an application I am not building and deploying everytime using an installer.

Comment: I've created a new image. Took me a while because when i tried to create a image with .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 i couldn't run any program. Now i'm getting a error reporting. The actual error is "System does not support 'iso-8859-1' encoding. Line 1, position 31." I've tried saving my file with different encondings but i keep on getting the same error.

Comment: @Jamiro14 So, in the end including the resource strings helped you :),  like ctake said it didn't solved your problem but it helped to correctly diagnose the real problem.

Comment: @Jamiro14: Never include both CF 2.0 and 3.5 in an OS.  It will fail.  Include only CF 3.5 (as the 3.5 runtimes can execute 2.0 assemblies just fine).

Comment: @garzanti yes including the strings was really helpful, it didn't solve my problem, but it helped.

Comment: @ctacke Yes, I know that now :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually attached with the debugger?  I ask becasue of the fact that you don't have exception messages available.  Those get deployed automatically when you are debugging (the CAB file is NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics`).

What we do know is that it's an XmlException, so it has nothing to do with the file location or it being locked (you'd get a different type of exception is that case).  Most likely you have invalid or malformed XML in the file you're trying to load.  You'd have to post the XML itself for use to know exactly, but as a test, simply replace your file with a simple XML file containing just a definition and a root node and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried several XML and they all produce the same error... I'm using VS2005 so no CF3.5 only 2.0. I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to say when you asked if i was actually attached to the debugger. I'm debugging my project in a WINCE device using VS.

Comment: I find it odd that Studio didn't deploy the resources file for you, but not shocked.  Studio does its own thing at times.  Manually deploy the resources CAB (path is in my answer) and see if you get any more useful info.